# Git: alternative for stash

Tags: git, git-extensions, git-worktree

I'm using **Git Extensions** for my projects. I really like it.
There is an issue that keeps bugging me and I'm pretty sure there is a trick in Git Extensions for it.
Here is the scenario:

- From master branch, I created 3 branches `A`, `B` and `C`.
- Started working in branch `A`, did some changes
- Switched to branch `B`, I still see changes made in `A` as they are not committed

  - I don't want to commit changes in `A` because I'm not done yet and I don't want this commit to appear in commit history
  - I don't want to stash changes in `A` because if I make changes in `B` and switch to `C`, I have to stash changes in `B` too ==> changes in `A` are gone: overridden by the new stash.

Can I make many stashes in different branches?
If not, whats the alternative for `stash`?
Is `commit` and `revert` `commit` my only option here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## ***`git worktree`***

Git worktree was introduced in 2007 under the `contrib` folder in git repo and was called `new-workdir`.

---

for example:

```
git worktree add <second path>
```

will create another folder on your computer which allow you to work on different branch simultaneously.

`git worktree` will create 2 separate working folders separated from each other while pointing to the same repository.

This will allow you do to any experimentals on the new worktree without having any effect on the repository itself. In the attached image you can see that there are **2 separate** working folder but both of them are using a single repo and share the content.

Here is a sample on how to create new worktree and what is the result of it:

[image]

---

> Can I make many stashes in different branches?

Yes you can but you want to avoid it. You can pop up stash to different branches than the one you originally stahed the sources.

> If not, whats the alternative of stash?

As explained above - use worktree

> Is commit and revert commit, my only option here?

Again: As explained above - use worktree

Comment: I like the idea of `worktree` but I don't know how to use it in Git Extensions GUI.

Comment: use it from git bash.

Comment: I will try. Thanks

Comment: The support for worktrees was added in GitExtensions-2.50 https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/releases/tag/v2.50RC1

Answer (score 2):

You *can* keep track of your stashes and apply them in any order you wish.  While on branch `A` type:

```
git stash save "stash_a"
```

You can similarly name stashes from branches `B` and `C`.  You can list all stashes by typing

```
git stash list
```

To apply a certain stash you can use

```
git stash pop stash@{n}
```

where `n` is the index of the stash.  Use the names you gave to correlate stashes with their respective indices in the stack.

You mentioned the following:

> I don't want to commit changes in A because I'm not done yet and I don't want this commit to appear in commit history.

Actually, there is nothing wrong with making a commit, because you can always *amend* that commit later on with no consequences, assuming that you either haven't pushed, or if you have pushed, that the branch isn't shared.  So an alternative to using `git stash` on branch `A` would actually be to just do this:

```
git commit -m 'WIP'
```

Then, when you return to branch `A` and complete the task, commit via this:

```
git commit --amend
```

Note that doing `git stash` actually creates 2 (or sometimes 3) commits under the hood.  So both methods I described rely on making commits in some way.  The worktree answer given by the @CodeWizard might be an alternative to using commits.

Comment: type `git stash list` and than you can view on which branch the commit was made and you can grab any stash you want

Comment: One more thing that's worth noting here: `git stash` makes its commits on *no* branch. This is why it's so easy to use `git stash` to *move* uncommitted changes from one branch to another: you save a new stash, then check out the branch, then apply and drop the saved stash. I find, however, that if there are a lot of saved stashes hanging around, I lose track of which one is which.

Comment: "Actually, there is nothing wrong with making a commit," - exactly! Aside from amend, you can also easily commit and then later come back to it and reset to the last commit before it (while leaving the work dir untouched) and just continue working where you left off. This of course works cleanly in terms of commits only as long as you haven't pushed the commit.